# How do we determine the order of the degeneracy of silicon bands?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

In an exercise on intrinsic semiconductors, I was asked to compute the effective state density in conduction and valence bands of Silicon (resp. $N_c(T)$ and $P_v(T)$), at $T=300$K. Those can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
N_c(T) = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{2m_c k_B T}{\pi \hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}
\end{equation} and
\begin{equation}
P_v(T) = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{2m_v k_B T}{\pi \hbar^2}\right)^{3/2},
\end{equation} with $m_c$ (resp. $m_v$) the effective mass of conduction (resp. valence) carriers and $k_B$ Boltzmann's constant. I know that one can account for the degeneracy of the bands by replacing the effective masses in the above formulae by
\begin{equation}
m_{c,v}^{3/2} \to \sum_i m_i^{3/2}
\end{equation} where $m_i$ is the effective mass corresponding to the $i$th extremum in the band.

What I do not understand is that in the solution, it is said that the degeneracy in the conduction band is of 6, while the degeneracy in the valence band is of $4 = 2+2$ due to the so called "heavy" and "light" holes, yielding
\begin{equation}
m_c^{3/2} \to 6 m_c^{3/2} , \qquad m_v^{3/2} \to 2 (m_{hh}^{3/2} + m_{lh}^{3/2}). 
\end{equation} Could someone enlighten me on these numbers?

I guess I am also a bit confused with the concept of heavy and light holes in the valence band so any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Bands with different curvature have different effective masses. The fact that the energies of the top of the two valence bands in silicon are the same is just a fact of the band structure.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you, I've just found this [page](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-holes-in-a-semiconductor-have-two-different-effective-masses-light-and-heavy) that gives a comprehensive explanation on the origin of heavy & light holes. [This page](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/ghosh/diss_htmse10.html#:~:text=The%20six%2Dfold%20degeneracy%20of,equally%2C%20making%20the%20transport%20isotropic.) also demonstrates the 6-fold degeneracy of the conduction band of silicon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! [This page](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-holes-in-a-semiconductor-have-two-different-effective-masses-light-and-heavy) gives a comprehensive explanation on the origin of heavy & light holes in semiconductors, while [this one](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/ghosh/diss_htmse10.html#:%7E:text=The%20six%2Dfold%20degeneracy%20of,equally%2C%20making%20the%20transport%20isotropic.) demonstrates the 6-fold degeneracy of the conduction band of silicon : "The six-fold degeneracy of the valleys arise due to the symmetry of the lattice along the [100], [010], and [001] directions".